# Google Workspace App script - Populate a team vacation calendar can't sync user calendar events

Tags: workspace

I follow this app script to create team vacation calendar and sync group members calendar events into. But find existing user calendar can't sync. When I creat new user account. That's work.
I have compare 2 users calendars setting. All of them are same setting.

After contact Google Workspace support. They said my app script and everything is correct and suggest raise issue in stack overflow ask google engineer. Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar

How to troubleshooting this issue and sovle it?